# cannot resolved method 'add(R.id.main_container,new HomeFragment())

Tags: android-studio

```
cannot resolved method 'add(R.id.main_container,new HomeFragment())
```

what is the meaning of this? can anyone please help me? newbie here. android studio. ive been trying to fix this but nothing happen.

Comment: Share your code that couse this error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be regarding import android.support.v4.app.Fragment or import android.app.Fragment;

If your HomeFragment might be using a support fragment.

Then use below one.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
```

If your HomeFragment might be be a fragment.
Then use

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
```

Comment: Thanksyou so much! That helps me! :)

Comment: @RosalynAbenio welcome :) and pls accept the answer and rate it up